# Existence of a sequence of intervals intersects every point of fat Cantor?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, solution-verification, cantor-set

The following is an exercise from Bruckner's Real Analysis:

> Let $C$ be a Cantor set in $[0, 1]$ of measure $α$ ($0 ≤ α<1$). Does there exist a sequence ${\{J_k}\}$ of intervals with $\sum_{k=1}^∞ m(J_k ) < ∞$ such that every point of the set $C$ lies in infinitely many of the intervals $J_k$?

My attempt: Let ${\{q_n}\}$ be an enumeration of $C \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and consider for each $n$ an interval of length $\dfrac{1}{2^n}$ symmetric around $q_n$. Consider minimum integer $j_1$ that some arbitrary but fixed point $x \in C$ belongs to it then that $I_{j_1}$ contains infinitely many $q_n$ take the next greater integer $j_2 \ge j_1$ such that it contains $x$, and repeat the process...

Am I right? If so, why a Cantor set with positive measure then if this argument holds for any set?

Comment: It’s entirely possible that $C\cap\Bbb Q=\varnothing$: there are Cantor sets contained in the irrationals.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Such a strange thing this Cantor set is!! .. can I modify the argument just by enumerating $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ then continue the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: If $\alpha>0$ there is an $n_0\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\sum_{k\ge n_0}m(J_k)<\alpha$, so $C\setminus\bigcup_{k\ge n_0}J_k\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: Your hint is clear and maybe useful to turn last inequality to $\bigcap_{k\ge n_0}J_k \setminus C\ne\varnothing$ but still how to proceed any further?

Comment: @L.G.: No, the set difference definitely has to go the way I wrote it. If $x\in C\setminus\bigcup_{k\ge n_0}J_k$, can $x$ belong to infinitely many of the intervals?

Comment: No it cannot, bc infinitely many intervals are removed and still x is there!

Comment: @L.G.: You’re right that it can’t, but it’s not enough to know that infinitely many intervals were removed: the crucial point is that **all but finitely many** of the intervals were removed. Specifically, if $x\in J_k$, then we know that $k<n_0$.

Comment: I understand your hints but not a bit more step I can take further. Could you write a detailed answer I am not that smart unfortunately

Comment: What is wrong with my argument if I only replace $C \cap \mathbb{Q}$ with $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @L.G.: You don’t have to go any further: you’ve seen that there must be a point in $C$ that is in only finitely many of the intervals $J_k$, so there is no sequence of intervals with the property stated in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @L.G.: You’re welcome.

Comment: C could've been any set of positive measure and still the argument holds, right? I mean being Cantor was not necessary?

Comment: @L.G.: Yes, that’s correct.